# recaptcha.net which Google suggested also is not working in China

Tags: recaptcha

Google suggests recaptcha can be used globally using recaptcha.net, but when I followed the steps and implemented it on a site it is not even loading. Any suggestions/help?

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

First replace `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>` with `<script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

Comment: So probably China’s censors simply added that alternative domain to their block lists by now … nothing much you can do about that.